# A single word for a secluded garden surrounded by a wall

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anybody give me a single word for a secluded garden surrounded by a wall?

Comment: Did you have the idea of the Secret Garden in mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually called ["walled garden"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walled_garden)

> A walled garden is specifically a
>   garden enclosed by high walls for
>   horticultural rather than security
>   purposes, though traditionally all
>   gardens have been hedged about or
>   walled for protection from animal or
>   human intruders. Garden walls may also
>   serve a decorative purpose, but their
>   essential function in the north
>   temperate zone has been to shelter the
>   garden from wind and frost.

Curiously, the literal meaning of the word ["paradise" IS "walled garden"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise) but it has long since lost that meaning

> The word "paradise" entered English
>   from the French paradis, inherited
>   from the Latin paradisus, from Greek
>   parádeisos (παράδεισος), and
>   ultimately from an Old Iranian root,
>   attested in Avestan as
>   pairi.daêza-. **The literal meaning
>   of this Eastern Old Iranian language
>   word is "walled (enclosure)",from
>   pairi- "around" + -diz "to create,
>   make".** The word is not attested in
>   other Old Iranian languages (these may
>   however be hypothetically
>   reconstructed, for example as Old
>   Persian *paridayda-).

Maybe you can also use [hortus conclosus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortus_conclusus)

> Hortus conclusus is a Latin term,
>   meaning literally "enclosed garden".
>   "The word 'garden' is at root the same
>   as the word 'yard'. It means an
>   enclosure", observed Derek Clifford,
>   at the outset of a series of essays on
>   garden design, in which he skirted the
>   conventions of the hortus
>   conclusus.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walled_garden) Thus, at their root,
>   both of the words in hortus conclusus
>   refer linguistically to enclosure.

Comment: @alwayslearning glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 12):

***Pleasance*** seems to fit the bill quite nicely. -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pleasance)

> (noun) A secluded enclosure or part of a garden, especially one attached to a large house.

Answer (score 4):

***Courtyard*** -- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/courtyard)

> (noun) a court open to the sky, especially one enclosed on all four sides.

Comment: That's what came to my mind, although a court does not necessarily have a garden.

Answer (score 1):

What came to mind are the ancient Roman homes where the second half of the house is surrounded by a *[peristyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristyle)*.  The use of the word peristyle would be specific to a colonnade with a covered walkway and may not always contain a garden.  However, I have seen *peristyle garden* and *peristyle courtyard* as alternatives. There is also a [cloister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloister), the medieval equivalent.

*Secret garden* is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite the same, but a "cloister" is a courtyard or garden surrounded by a covered walkway. Here is one example.

[image]

Comment: You could always have included a representative image in your answer. Answers should be complete and stand on their own; it should not be necessary to search for additional resources (or even, really, to click on a link except for verification of a quote or citation).

Comment: Good answer, and fyi the term was already mentioned in another answer, although not highlighted for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try ***plantiecrub***, although this source [here](http://www.shetlanddialect.org.uk/john-j-grahams-shetland-dictionary.php?word=1825) suggests it would be for growing cabbage.

> noun - a small circular dry-stone enclosure for growing cabbage plants.

Answer (score 0):

***Bower*** comes to mind. -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bower)

> (noun) 1. A pleasant shady place under trees or climbing plants in a garden or wood.

Comment: I think _bower_ may be a very apt word for what the poster is describing—but to strengthen your answer and help future visitors to this page understand why it may be a good choice, please consider adding a relevant dictionary definition of _bower_ to your answer.